# Shift placeholder on focus in text field

Tags: mobile-text-entry

I have seen some websites where the placeholder in a text box shifts up and lets the user continue typing in the input box, what is this behavior called ?

```
--------------
Email-Id
--------------

--------------
Email-Id (assume smaller font here)
| (input area) 
--------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [**float label**](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/) pattern.

[image: when you type in a field, the placeholder in the field moves up to become a label above the field]Image source: [a blog post by Matt D Smith, the apparent creator of the pattern](http://mds.is/float-label-pattern/)

Comment: Thank you ! I kept searching persistent placeholder, shift placeholder and nothing came up. Thanks again :)